# I want to load a YAML file, possibly edit the data, and then dump it again. How can I preserve formatting?

Tags: formatting, yaml

*This question tries to collect information spread over questions about different languages and YAML implementations in a mostly language-agnostic manner.*

Suppose I have a YAML file like this:

```yaml
first:
  - foo: {a: "b"}
  - "bar": [1, 2, 3]
second: |   # some comment
  some long block scalar value
```

I want to load this file into an native data structure, possibly change or add some values, and dump it again. However, when I dump it, the original formatting is not preserved:

- The scalars are formatted differently, e.g. `"b"` loses its quotation marks, the value of `second` is not a literal block scalar anymore, etc.
- The collections are formatted differently, e.g. the mapping value of `foo` is written in block style instead of the given flow style, similarly the sequence value of `"bar"` is written in block style
- The order of mapping keys (e.g. `first`/`second`) changes
- The comment is gone
- The indentation level differs, e.g. the items in `first` are not indented anymore.

How can I preserve the formatting of the original file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Preface: Throughout this answer, I mention some popular YAML implementations. Those mentions are never exhaustive since I do not know all YAML implementations out there.*

*I will use YAML terms for data structures: Atomic text content (even numbers) is a **scalar**. Item sequences, known elsewhere as arrays or lists, are **sequences**. A collection of key-value pairs, known elsewhere as dictionary or hash, is a **mapping**.*

*If you are using Python, using [ruamel](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) will help you preserve quite some formatting since it implements round-tripping up to native structures. However, it isn't perfect and cannot preserve all formatting.*

### Background

The process of loading YAML is also a process of losing information. Let's have a look at the process of loading/dumping YAML, as given in the spec:

[image]

When you are loading a YAML file, you are executing some or all of the steps in the **Load** direction, starting at the **Presentation (Character Stream)**. YAML implementations usually promote their most high-level APIs, which load the YAML file all the way to **Native (Data Structure)**. This is true for most common YAML implementations, e.g. PyYAML/ruamel, SnakeYAML, go-yaml, and Ruby's YAML module. Other implementations, such as libyaml and yaml-cpp, only provide deserialization up to the **Representation (Node Graph)**, possibly due to restrictions of their implementation languages (loading into native data structures requires either compile-time or runtime reflection on types).

The important information for us is what is contained in those boxes. Each box mentions information which is not available anymore in the box left to it. So this means that *styles* and *comments*, according to the YAML specification, are only present in the actual YAML file content, but are discarded as soon as the YAML file is *parsed*. For you, this means that once you have loaded a YAML file to a native data structure, all information about how it originally looked in the input file is gone. Which means that when you dump the data, the YAML implementation chooses a representation it deems useful for your data. Some implementations let you give general hints/options, e.g. that all scalars should be quoted, but that doesn't help you restore the original formatting.

Thankfully, this diagram only describes the *logical* process of loading YAML; a conforming YAML implementation does not need to slavishly conform to it. Most implementations actually preserve data longer than they need to. This is true for PyYAML/ruamel, SnakeYAML, go-yaml, yaml-cpp, libyaml and others. In all these implementations, the *style* of scalars, sequences and mappings is remembered up until the **Representation (Node Graph)** level.

On the other hand, *comments* are discarded rather early since they do not belong to an event or node (the exceptions here is ruamel which links comments to the following event, and go-yaml which remembers comments before, at and after the line that created a node). Some YAML implementations (libyaml, SnakeYAML) provide access to a token stream which is even more low-level than the *Event Tree*. This token stream does contain comments, however it is only usable for doing things like syntax highlighting, since the APIs do not contain methods for *consuming* the token stream again.

### So what to do?

#### Loading & Dumping

If you need to only load your YAML file and then dump it again, use one of the lower-level APIs of your implementation to only load the YAML up until the **Representation (Node Graph)** or **Serialization (Event Tree)** level. The API functions to search for are **compose**/**parse** and **serialize**/**present** respectively.

It is preferable to use the *Event Tree* instead of the *Node Graph* as some implementations already forget the original order of mapping keys (due to internally using hashmaps) when *composing*. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268892/dumping-values-with-quotes-with-snakeyaml), for example, details loading / dumping events with SnakeYAML.

Information that is already lost in the event stream of your implementation, for example comments in most implementations, is impossible to preserve. Also impossible to preserve is scalar layout, like in this example:

```yaml
"1 \x2B 1"
```

This loads as string `"1 + 1"` after resolving the escape sequence. Even in the event stream, the information about the escape sequence has already been lost in all implementations I know. The event only remembers that it was a double-quoted scalar, so writing it back will result in:

```yaml
"1 + 1"
```

Similarly, a folded block scalar (starting with `>`) will usually not remember where line breaks in the original input have been folded into space characters.

To sum up, loading to the *Event Tree* and dumping again will usually preserve:

- Style: unquoted/quoted/block scalars, flow/block collections (sequences & mappings)
- Order of keys in mappings
- YAML tags and anchors

You will usually lose:

- Information about escape sequences and line breaks in flow scalars
- Indentation and non-content spacing
- Comments – unless the implementation specifically supports putting them in events and/or nodes

If you use the *Node Graph* instead of the *Event Tree*, you will likely lose anchor representations (i.e. that `&foo` may be written out as `&a` later with all aliases referring to it using `*a` instead of `*foo`). You might also lose key order in mappings. Some APIs, like go-yaml, don't provide access to the *Event Tree*, so you have no choice but to use the *Node Graph* instead.

#### Modifying Data

If you want to modify data and still preserve what you can of the original formatting, you need to manipulate your data without loading it to a native structure. This usually means that you operate on YAML scalars, sequences and mappings, instead of *strings*, *numbers*, *lists* or whatever structures the target programming language provides.

You have the option to either process the *Event Tree* or the *Node Graph* (assuming your API gives you access to it). Which one is better usually depends on what you want to do:

- The *Event Tree* is usually provided as stream of events. It may be better for large data since you do not need to load the complete data in memory; instead you inspect each event, track your position in the input structure, and place your modifications accordingly. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49352692/347964) shows how to append items giving a path and a value to a given YAML file with PyYAML's event API.
- The *Node Graph* is better for highly structured data. If you use anchors and aliases, they will be resolved there but you will probably lose information about their names (as explained above). Unlike with events, where you need to track the current position yourself, the data is presented as complete graph here, and you can just descend into the relevant sections.

In any case, you need to know a bit about YAML type resolution to work with the given data correctly. When you load a YAML file into a declared native structure (typical in languages with a static type system, e.g. Java or Go), the YAML processor will map the YAML structure to the target type if that's possible. However, if no target type is given (typical in scripting languages like Python or Ruby, but also possible in Java), types are deduced from node content and style.

Since we are not working with native loading because we need to preserve formatting information, this type resolution will not be executed. However, you need to know how it works in two cases:

- When you need to decide on the type of a scalar node or event, e.g. you have a scalar with content `42` and need to know whether that is a *string* or *integer*.
- When you need to create a new event or node that should later be loaded as a specific type. E.g. if you create a scalar containing `42`, you might want to control whether that it is loaded as *integer* `42` or *string* `"42"` later.

I won't discuss all the details here; in most cases, it suffices to know that if a *string* is encoded as a scalar but looks like something else (e.g. a number), you should use a quoted scalar.

Depending on your implementation, you may come in touch with YAML *tags*. Seldom used in YAML files (they look like e.g. `!!str`, `!!map`, `!!int` and so on), they contain type information about a node which can be used in collections with heterogeneous data. More importantly, YAML defines that all nodes without an explicit tag will be assigned one as part of type resolution. This may or may not have already happened at the *Node Graph* level. So in your node data, you may see a node's tag even when the original node does not have one.

Tags starting with two exclamation marks are actually *shorthands*, e.g. `!!str` is a shorthand for `tag:yaml.org,2002:str`. You may see either in your data, since implementations handle them quite differently.

Important for you is that when you create a node or event, you may be able and may also need to assign a tag. If you don't want the output to contain an explicit tag, use the non-specific tags `!` for non-plain scalars and `?` for everything else on event level. On node level, consult your implementation's documentation about whether you need to supply resolved tags. If not, same rule for the non-specific tags applies. If the documentation does not mention it (few do), try it out.

So to sum up: You modify data by loading either the *Event Tree* or the *Node Graph*, you add, delete or modify events or nodes in the data you get, and then you *present* the modified data as YAML again. Depending on what you want to do, it may help you to create the data you want to add to your YAML file as native structure, serialize it to YAML and then load it again as *Node Graph* or *Event Tree*. From there, you can include it in the structure of the YAML file you want to modify.

### Conclusion / TL;DR

YAML has not been designed for this task. In fact, it has been defined as a *serialization language*, assuming that your data is authored as native data structures in some programming language and from there dumped to YAML. However, in reality, YAML is used a lot for configuration, meaning that you typically write YAML by hand and then load it into native data structures.

This contrast is the reason why it is so difficult to modify YAML files while preserving formatting: The YAML format has been designed as *transient* data format, to be written by one application, and then to be loaded by another (or the same) application. In that process, preserving formatting does not matter. It does, however, for data that is checked-in to version control (you want your diff to only contain the line(s) with data you actually changed), and other situations where you write your YAML by hand, because you want to keep style consistent.

There is no perfect solution for changing exactly one data item in a given YAML file and leaving everything else intact. Loading a YAML file does not give you a view of the YAML file, it gives you the content it describes. Therefore, everything that is not part of the described content – most importantly, comments and whitespace – is extremely hard to preserve.

If format preservation is important to you and you can't live with the compromises made by the suggestions in this answer, YAML is not the right tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to challenge the accepted answer. Whether you can preserve comments, the order of map keys, or other features depends on the YAML parsing library that you use. For starters, the library needs to give you access to the parsed YAML as a YAML Document, which is a collection of YAML nodes. These nodes can contain metadata besides the actual key/value pairs. The kinds of metadata that your library chooses to store will determine how much of the initial YAML document you can preserve. I will not speak for all languages and all libraries, but Golang's most popular YAML parsing library, [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) supports parsing YAML into a YAML document tree and serializing YAML document back, and preserves:

- comments
- the order of keys
- anchors and aliases
- scalar blocks

However, it does not preserve indentation, insignificant whitespace, and some other minor things. On the plus side, it allows modifying the YAML document and there's another library,
[yaml-jsonpath](https://github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath) that simplifies browsing the YAML node tree. Example:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "testing"
)

func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    var n yaml.Node 
    y := []byte(`# Comment
t: &t
  - x: 1 # anchor
a:
    b: *t # alias
    b: |
        cccc
        dddd
`)
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(y, &n)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    y2, _ := yaml.Marshal(&n)
    assert.Equal(t, y, y2)
}
```

Comment: [Counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063156/347964) for go-yaml preserving comments. Though the comment content is preserved, its position is not. Counter-example for preserving scalar blocks: `--- >\na\nb\nc` (replace `\n` with actual newlines), linebreaks will not be preserved. I am unsure what you want to say with this answer; I did state in my answer that go-yaml preserves more information than required as per spec.

Comment: I wrote this question & answer to do two things: Firstly, tell people that YAML is not designed to keep representation, and that there is no perfect solution for it (even ruamel isn't always able to). Secondly, help people to assess what they *can* preserve with the implementation of their choice and *how* they can do it. You didn't contradict anything my answer says.

Comment: @flyx Your answer came up when a colleague of mine pointed out that per your answer, YAML wasn't designed to preserve the formatting as it's a serialization language. It gives an impression that preserving formatting in YAML is technically difficult which is not consistent with my understanding of the YAML syntax. I made an example of go-yaml but I believe that go-yaml can be improved to preserve even more features, including indentation and insignificant whitespace.

Comment: „*preserving formatting in YAML is technically difficult*“ is exactly the point I am making. This is based on explicit statements in the spec, like how certain information including comments, key order and node style must not convey content information. While is is technically possible to build a complete AST of a YAML file which would allow complete preservation, none of the popular implementations, including go-yaml, work like this *because they follow what the spec says*. Saying that implementations could be improved doesn't help a user who searches for a solution with existing tools.

Comment: My answer can help someone by listing exactly what features go-yaml v3 preserves, gives a reproducible example of preserving many of the YAML features the author is asking for, and suggests another library to help manipulate the YAML document. In addition, my answer is concise and practical, which is helpful to someone who is trying to get an answer without having to read the whole theory of syntax analysis. I suggest to let the readers decide which answer is better, and yours has a 15 point lead.