# how can I print a 2d list with the 2 minus symbols on the same line with yaml cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I would like to create the following Yaml using yaml-cpp:

```
  steps:
    - - name: flip-coin
        template: flip-coin
    - - name: heads
        template: heads
        when: "{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == heads"
      - name: tails
        template: tails
        when: "{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == tails"
```

But I cannot print the minus symbols on the same line. This is what I am getting:

```
  steps:
    -
      - name: flip-coin
        template: flip-coin
    -
      - name: heads
        template: heads
        when: "{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == heads"
      - name: tails
        template: tails
        when: "{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == tails"
```

My code is

```
    YAML::Node node;
    node["steps"][0][0]["name"]="flip-coin";
    node["steps"][0][0]["template"]="flip-coin";

    node["steps"][1][0]["name"]="heads";
    node["steps"][1][0]["template"]="heads";
    node["steps"][1][0]["when"]="{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == heads";

    node["steps"][1][1]["name"]="tails";
    node["steps"][1][1]["template"]="tails";
    node["steps"][1][1]["when"]="{{steps.flip-coin.outputs.result}} == tails";

    YAML::Emitter out;
    out << node;
    std::cout << out.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [existing manipulators](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/include/yaml-cpp/emittermanip.h) do not contain anything that would enable you to configure compact inline sequence notation, so I am pretty sure this isn't possible.

Generally, YAML is not designed to fine-tune character by character how your output looks like. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964). Spacing information is a presentation detail and not present in your data. Therefore, your data is presented as the implementation sees fit and except for the available manipulators, you can't do anything about it.