# How to parse general yaml in golang with comments preserved?

Tags: go, yaml

I am playing with golang yaml v3 library. The goal is to parse any yaml (that means that I don't have predefined structure) from file with comments, be able to set or unset any value in the resulting tree and write it back to file.

However, I have encountered quite strange behavior. As you can see in the code below, if the main type passed to the Unmarshal function is `interface{}`, no comments are preserved and library uses maps and slices to represent the structure of yaml. On the other hand, if I use (in this case) `[]yaml.Node` structure, it does represent all nodes internally as `yaml.Node` or `[]yaml.Node`. This is more or less what I want, because it allows comment preservation. However, it is not a general solution because there are at least two distinct scenarios - either the YAML starts with an array or with a map and I am not sure how to elegantly deal with both situations.

Could you possibly point me in the right direction and elaborate on why does the library behaves this way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Document interface{} // change this to []yaml.Node and it will work with comments // change it to yaml.Node and it will not work

var data string = ` # Employee records
-  martin:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - python
      - perl
      - pascal
-  tabitha:
    name: Tabitha Bitumen
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - lisp
      - fortran
      - erlang
`

func toSlice(slice interface{}) []interface{} {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("InterfaceSlice() given a non-slice type")
    }

    ret := make([]interface{}, s.Len())

    for i:=0; i<s.Len(); i++ {
        ret[i] = s.Index(i).Interface()
    }

    return ret
}

func main() {
    var d Document
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    slice := toSlice(d)
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(slice[0]).Kind())

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(d))
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(d).Kind())
    output, err := yaml.Marshal(&d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On the other hand, if I use (in this case) []yaml.Node structure, it does represent all nodes internally as yaml.Node or []yaml.Node.

That is not accurate. go-yaml lets you leave any sub-tree of your structure as `yaml.Node` possibly for later processing. Inside this node, everything is represented as a `yaml.Node`, and a node that is a collection (sequence or mapping) just happens to store its children as `[]yaml.Node`. But no node is directly represented as `[]yaml.Node`.

When you deserialize into `[]yaml.Node`, you deserialize the top-level node into a native structure (a slice) while leaving the children unconstructed (the process of loading a YAML node into a native structure is called *construction* in the spec).

go-yaml does not really support

```golang
type Document yaml.Node
```

but if you just do

```golang
var d yaml.Node
```

the comment will be preserved as well (`toSlice` will not work anymore obviously):

```yaml
- # Employee records
  martin:
      name: Martin D'vloper
      job: Developer
      skills:
        - python
        - perl
        - pascal
- tabitha:
      name: Tabitha Bitumen
      job: Developer
      skills:
        - lisp
        - fortran
        - erlang
```

Now as we can see, the position of the comment differs. This is because go-yaml just stores in the `yaml.Node` that represents the list item that *„there has been a comment before this list item“*. The information about where exactly the comment has been located was lost. You should be thankful that you have *any* information about the comment because most YAML implementations scrap them far earlier since the spec says that comments must not convey content information.

You may want to read [I want to load a YAML file, possibly edit the data, and then dump it again. How can I preserve formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964) which goes into detail about why, when and how information is lost during loading of a YAML file. TL;DR: It is impossible (without basically doing parsing yourself) to load a YAML file and dump it back while preserving all formatting and if that is your goal, YAML is the wrong tool for you.

Comment: I have been severely hit by such a project...

Answer (score 1):

When go-yaml parses a YAML document, it always creates a YAML node tree first. Whether or not it then converts that node tree into a plain Golang object, depends on the type of the `out` argument passed to `Unmarshall`. Here's a code snippet from go-yaml sources:

```golang
func (d *decoder) unmarshal(n *Node, out reflect.Value) (good bool) {
    // ...
    if out.Type() == nodeType {
        out.Set(reflect.ValueOf(n).Elem())
        return true
    }
    // ...
}
```

Essentially, go-yaml skips the conversion of the node tree if the supplied argument is a pointer to `yaml.Node`. When your parameter type is `interface{}` or anything else other than `yaml.Node`, it will do the conversion.

In order to preserve comments and allow a map, an array, or even a single value at the top level, just pass a `*yaml.Node` as a second parameter to `yaml.Unmarshal`:

```golang
var n yaml.Node
err := yaml.Unmarshal(bytes, &n)
```

In case of an array being at the top level, the root node will contain the YAML nodes of array elements as its children.