# How to add a mapping node to a YAML file without affecting comments

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I have below yaml file

Input:

```
# Emp1 details
Employee1: &dept
  DeptCode: ABC
  Tower: T1
```

I want to add below yaml content with mapping key

```
# Emp2 details  
Employee2: &IT
  <<: *dept
  Block: firstfloor
```

So my final output:

```
# Emp1 details
Employee1: &dept
  DeptCode: ABC
  Tower: T1
  
# Emp2 details  
Employee2: &IT
  <<: *dept
  Block: firstfloor
```

We can achieve this by using the below code, but comments are removed from the YAML file while writing back. I have referred t[his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412467/modify-content-without-affective-comments-and-other-using-yamldotnet-in-c-sharp), but I am not sure how to add a mapping node by using emitter and parser.

```
        var reader = new StreamReader("Input.yaml");
        yaml.Load(reader);
        rootNode = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;
        var newNode = new YamlMappingNode();
        newNode.Anchor = "IT";
        var dept = rootNode["dept"];
        newNode.Add("<<", dept);
        newNode.Add("Block", "firstfloor");
        rootNode.Add("Employee2",newNode )
```