# Is there a way to keep initial yaml format of a file when updating programatically with java?

Tags: java, yaml

I am working on a tool to automate mass-updating several pom files and pipeline files.

The pom files I am able to update and successfully push to bitbucket but am having an issue updating the yaml file as I don't see much of an option out there to update yaml files directly.

The pipeline yaml we have are quite big and I am wondering if there is a way to keep the same format of the existing pipeline file, sample :

```
build:
  property1: .
  property2: artifactory
  property3: false
deploy:
  property1: test
  property2: test2
  env:
    property1: true
    property2: '"template"'
```

I am able to successfully update the above yaml using the below code :

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    Map<String, Object> pipeline = objectMapper.readValue(
            new File(DEFAULT_DIR + serviceName + "\\pipeline.yml"),
            new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });

    Map<String, Object> build = (Map<String, Object>) pipeline.get("build");
    build.put("property1", "d");
    
    objectMapper.writeValue(new File(DEFAULT_DIR + serviceName + "\\pipeline.yml"), pipeline);
```

After writeValue creates the new yaml file, we see quotes around all the properties in the new yaml.  I assume this is from the writeValue method from ObjectMapper.

```
build:
  property1: "."
  property2: "artifactory"
  property3: false
deploy:
  property1: "test"
  property2: "test2"
  env:
    property1: true
    property2: "\"template\""
```

Is this possible to keep the initial format of the yaml file without the quotes and the `"\" \""` we are seeing after objectMapper writes the file?  We have specific requirements for this layout in order for our Jenkins builds to work correctly.

Comment: Valid yaml is valid yaml. The actual issue seems to be your Jenkins build, which doesn't accept yaml with a different format although it's actually valid yaml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to load a YAML file, possibly edit the data, and then dump it again. How can I preserve formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891174/i-want-to-load-a-yaml-file-possibly-edit-the-data-and-then-dump-it-again-how)