# Python yaml dump emojis as is

Tags: python, encoding, yaml, pyyaml

I am using `python 3.9.5`, and `PyYaml 5.4.1`.

I have a file `t.yml` with the following content.

```yaml
- ⬆️
```

I have written a simple python code, to read the yaml file and dump it back.

```py
import yaml

with open("t.yml") as file:
    con = yaml.safe_load(file)
    print(con)
    with open("t.yml","w") as file:
        yaml.dump(con,file)
```

The output of the code is:

```sh
['⬆️']
```

After dumping the yaml, the `t.yml` file becomes like this:

```yaml
- "\u2B06\uFE0F\U0001F622"
```

How can I dump the emojis in the exact same format, I loaded them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, YAML loses information when loading a file ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964)) so you cannot always dump it exactly the way it is written, since the information on how it was written has been lost.

In this case the solution is to set `allow_unicode`:

```py
import sys,yaml

input = """
- ⬆️
"""

con = yaml.safe_load(input)
yaml.dump(con,sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True)
```

Output:

```yaml
- ⬆️
```

Comment: for some reason google collab notebooks fail here with `ReaderError: unacceptable character #x1f622: special characters are not allowed
  in "<unicode string>", position 5`  https://imgur.com/a/c7S1fGN

Comment: @andilabs That might be an IPython problem but I'm no expert on that. I suggest asking a new question if you want an answer from someone knowledgable.