# How can I update yaml with multiple config

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file and want to change few parameters of the same file `temp.yaml`.

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: first
cmp:
- Some: first
  top:
    top_rate: 16000
    audio_device: "pulse"

---
name: second
components:
- name: second
  parameters:
    always_on: true
    timeout: 200000
```

I am able to open the file using `yaml.load_all` But how can I modify and dump data into same file. There is a method `dump_all` but am unsure of it's usage.

```
import yaml

with open('temp.yaml') as f:
    temp = yaml.safe_load_all(f)
    for t in temp:
        if t['name'] == 'first':
            t['cmp'][0]['Some'] = 'Result'
        if t['name'] == 'second':
            t['components']['parameters']['always_on'] = False
```

How can I dump it back to `temp.yaml`.  So that it look like

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: first
cmp:
- Some: Result
  top:
    top_rate: 16000
    audio_device: "pulse"

---
name: second
components:
- name: second
  parameters:
    always_on: false
    timeout: 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'r+'`:

```py
with open('temp.yaml', 'r+') as f:
    temp = yaml.safe_load_all(f)
    for t in temp:
        if t['name'] == 'first':
            t['cmp'][0]['Some'] = 'Result'
        if t['name'] == 'second':
            t['components']['parameters']['always_on'] = False
    # reset to position 0
    f.seek(0)
    yaml.safe_dump_all(test, f)
    # if new file is shorter than original file, truncate additional bytes
    f.truncate()
```

Mind that empty lines will not be preserved as they are discarded by the YAML parser. Quoted scalars like `"pulse"` will become unquoted because the information about quotation is lost when loading the data into native structures.

For more information about preserving style, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964).