# Ansible from_yaml is removing double quotation and position change after combine filter

Tags: ansible, yaml

Below is my program. When I tried to convert using from_yaml and write back the file, it removing the double quotation with single quotation. Is there a way to resovle it

```
- slurp:
    src: "/home/myname/config.yml"
  register: fileContent

- set_fact:
    fileContent: "{{ fileContent['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml | combine (myvariable) }}"

- copy:
    content: "{{ fileContent}}"
    dest: "/home/myname/config.yml"
```

sample config.yml

```
key:
  key:
    key1: "value"
    key2:
      key1: "value"
      key2: "value"
```

Also when combine, why the position of element changing. is there a way to maintain the position just change value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please ensure that you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): Keys in YAML must be unique, you cannot have `key:` two times in the same mapping (lines 3-4 and 5-6 in your config.yml). What is the other file? It also uses YAML syntax so it is obviously not a „program“. It refers to `myname.config.yml`, is that your `config.yml`? Where does `fileContent['content']` come from (it is not in your `config.yml`)? What is the desired and the actual output?

Comment: Hi. I have only 1 file which is config.yml. I have updated the config file. One of issue is i not quite sure why double quotation is being replaced with single quotation

Comment: Your problem is probably what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964) and if so, I don't think you can avoid it at this level. Why is it an issue that the quotation is changed?

Comment: Hi, the output file need be in double quotation for later processing. Besides why combine the allignment of key value changing. I get the expected result but the order is changing. Any idea?

Comment: Because declaration order of keys in a yaml dict has absolutely no importance, is not guaranteed to be stable and should not be relied upon. Else use a list. This and quotation changes is a non issue: the resulting data structure is absolutely identical. If your own "later processing" tool does not like that, then you should fix it (or change the data structure).

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Is there a way to maintain the position just change the value?**"*

A: No. There isn't such a filter available in Ansible which would preserve this format. If you need any special format you'll have to use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host).

Except for the changed formatting, your code should be working fine, actually. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - slurp:
        src: config.yml
      register: fileContent
    - set_fact:
        fileContent: "{{ fileContent.content|
                         b64decode|from_yaml|
                         combine(myvariable) }}"
      vars:
        myvariable:
          next_key:
            key1: "value"
            key2:
              key1: "value"
              key2: "value"
    - copy:
        content: "{{ fileContent }}"
        dest: config2.yml
```

gives valid JSON

```yaml
shell> cat config2.yml 
{"key": {"key": {"key1": "value", "key2": {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}}}, "next_key": {"key1": "value", "key2": {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}}}
```

The content of the file depends on formating. For example the default JSON above. You can change it to YAML, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: "{{ fileContent|to_nice_yaml }}"
        dest: config2.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat config2.yml 
key:
    key:
        key1: value
        key2:
            key1: value
            key2: value
next_key:
    key1: value
    key2:
        key1: value
        key2: value
```

or you can get nice JSON by using the filter *to_nice_json*, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: "{{ fileContent|to_nice_json }}"
        dest: config2.yml
```

gives

```
shell> cat config2.yml 
{
    "key": {
        "key": {
            "key1": "value",
            "key2": {
                "key1": "value",
                "key2": "value"
            }
        }
    },
    "next_key": {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": {
            "key1": "value",
            "key2": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i notice that double quotation is changed to single quotation due to form_yaml. is there a way to resolve it