# How to update configmap data part from powershell?

Tags: powershell, yaml

Below is the configmap sample from kubernetes.

Is there anyway to update the configmap data part from powershell?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: database-configmap
data:
  config: |
    dbport=5432
    dcname=
    dbssl=false
    locktime=3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [powershell-yaml](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml) but you probably want to call [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) from Powershell instead because `yq` can keep the `config` value a literal block scalar while using `powershell-yaml` will probably convert it to a double-quoted scalar. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964) for some background on that.

If you want to change the content of the `config` value, mind that from a YAML perspective, it is a single scalar. The key/value separation with `=` is not something YAML recognizes. `yq` provides [regex replacement](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#substitute-replace-string) in scalars which may or may not be sufficient for your use-case.