# How to update the values programmatically in yaml that has pipe operator using python?

Tags: yaml

I have the below test.yaml file where I am trying to update the revision number using python but it mess up the values, any idea how to fix it?

```
spec:
  source:
     helm:
      valueFiles:
      - ../secrets/secrets.yaml
      values: |
        custom:
          address:
            domain: services-uat.com
            port: "80"
        revision: 1.0.1
```

Python code:

```
    version = "1.0.2"
    resource_file = yaml.safe_load(open('test.yaml'))
    source_exist = resource_file["spec"]["source"].get("helm")
    VERSION_MATCHSTR = r"\s*revision\s*:\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"

    revision_to_replace = re.search(VERSION_MATCHSTR, source_exist["values"]).group(
        1
    )
    logger.info(f"Revision {revision_to_replace} will be replaced with {version}")

    values_with_updated_version = source_exist["values"].replace(
        revision_to_replace, f"{version}"
    )
    resource_file["spec"]["source"]["helm"].update(
        {"values": values_with_updated_version}
    )
    with open('test.yaml', "w") as file:
        yaml.safe_dump(resource_file, file)
```

Output:

```
spec:
  source:
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - ../secrets/secrets.yaml
      values: "custom:\n  address:\n    domain: services-uat.com\n\
        \    port: \"80\"\nrevision: 1.0.2\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

In all seriousness, if you don't parse the `values` content as YAML, parsing the outer content only gives you a false sense of generality of your code. If you're using RegEx anyway, why not simply do it for the whole file:

```py
import re

input = """
spec:
  source:
     helm:
      valueFiles:
      - ../secrets/secrets.yaml
      values: |
        custom:
          address:
            domain: services-uat.com
            port: "80"
        revision: 1.0.1
"""

version = "1.0.2"
print(re.sub(r'(revision\s*:\s*)\d+\.\d+\.\d+', r'\g<1>' + version, input))
```

And if this is not feasible because it could match something else it shouldn't, I would suggest putting those values into an own `valueFile` so that you can easily update it there.

Keeping YAML style is generally impossible (i.e. there are cases where you just can't), though you *can* exercise some control over it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964).