# Parsing YAML containing multiple documents

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have YAML file ([Unity YAML](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/understanding-unitys-serialization-language-yaml)) which contains multiple documents:

```yaml
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!1 &500710038956159860
GameObject:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
--- !u!4 &7386865245216119872
Transform:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
```

yaml-cpp parse seems incomplete:

```cpp
YAML::Node map = YAML::Load(loaded_map);
fmt::print("{}\n", YAML::Dump(map));
```

prints only first document (and misses it's tag)

```
!<tag:unity3d.com,2011:1>
GameObject:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
```

Is it possible to get other documents and their tags (see missing `&500710038956159860`)?
Or is there other library capable of doing this?

Comment: What you call a "tag" is actually a YAML anchor that allows the resulting object tree to have multiple pointers to the same node. Many YAML libraries have a different API for loading one document and for loading multiple documents.

Comment: [Understanding Unity’s serialization language, YAML](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/understanding-unitys-serialization-language-yaml) .. and [YAML Class ID Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ClassIDReference.html) what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @derHugo For now I am just researching. End goal is to put data from unity's yaml to my own C++ structures. For example game objects and their coordinates/transformation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The given input is invalid YAML since a `%TAG` directive specifies a named handle only for one document, and thus, `!u!` is an unknown handle in the second document. No conforming YAML implementation should accept this. See [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#91-documents):

> Each document is completely independent from the rest.

Directives belong with the following document.

Concerning yaml-cpp, there is

```cpp
auto documents = YAML::LoadAll(loaded_map);
```

which gives you all documents, but there's no corresponding `YAML::DumpAll`.

Very few libraries support writing `%TAG` directives, in fact, the only one I know of that can do this is my own, [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org).

Very few libraries support preserving the anchors in the input, the only one I know of is [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml). Usually, implementations do not emit anchors unless they are referenced, and autogenerate anchor names if they need anchors. They are a presentation detail, after all, and specified to not convey content information.

Generally, YAML is [not a format designed to be round-tripping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60891174/347964) and no implementation is capable of completely reproduce the original style, because the spec clearly states in lots of places that several syntax features are presentation details that should be of no importance to the caller.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. Didn't know about issues with round-tripping before. Perhaps I should approach my goal from different angle. Especially if format is invalid, which is beyond my control.

Comment: `%TAG` is a *very* exotic feature and almost no-one uses it, therefore even stable YAML implementations in the wild may have issues with it due to little testing. The fact that whatever Unity is using accepts your input is a good indicator for that. Also YAML 1.2 is around since 2009, so them using `%YAML 1.1` screams „keep away from this undermaintained stuff as far as possible“.